# Applying bounce messages for unrecognized/catch-all addresses in Google Workspace

Tags: email, routes, google-workspace, email-bounces, catch-all

**Short version: I want to be able to continue to use my catch-all email system in Google Workspace while applying a bounce message to blocked senders that shows the actual recipient, not the recipient defined in the catch-all settings.**

I currently have a catch-all set up for a custom domain in Google Workspace with only one user (user@domain.com). Any unrecognized address routes to that user, and basically all my addresses are "unrecognized," using the logic of service@domain.com for external accounts. For example, my Netflix account would be registered to netflix@domain.com with all email routing to user@domain.com.

For spammy domains and annoying senders, I have address lists mapped to blocked senders in the Google Workspace admin. The result should be that messages from blocked senders get a bounce message set in blocked senders settings that would say something like, "Your message cannot be delivered." However, in the catch-all settings, I have selected the option to "Suppress bounces from this recipient" so as not to reveal the actual user in the bounce message—any bounce message would reveal "user@domain.com" instead of "service@domain.com."

The question is whether it is possible to use an email list that would bypass the catch-all and then correctly apply the blocked senders settings to deliver the bounce message with the actual recipient address used by the sender. Testing this is quite a pain, which is why I'm wondering if anyone has done this before.

**Tried:**
Applied blocked senders settings for spammy domains/senders

Applied "Suppress bounces from this recipient" in catch-all settings

Result: no bounce message for blocked senders (email logs will just show that the message was delivered).

**Tried:**
Applied blocked senders settings for spammy domains/senders

Removed "Suppress bounces from this recipient" in catch-all settings

Result: bounce message for blocked senders that reveals user@domain.com instead of the actual recipient address

**Desired result: bounce message for blocked senders that reveals [*]@domain.com**